# Cannot use CTRL + F and UN/COMMENT

Tags: bugs, windows, menu

I would like to ask a question with Mathematica 9.0.1.
I find that both

1. FIND: CTRL + F
2. UN/COMMENT: ALT + /

become unavailable. Pressing the shortkey or selecting from the menu could not activate the command. Previously with version 8.0.4.0, they were both fine.
[image] 
Does anyone know how to fix it?

Jimmy

Comment: On the other hand, I find the two commands are both available in "Help" notebooks. For example, if there are illustration scripts in any help document, I can use "CTRL + F" to find selection's occurrence within the help notebook, or use "ALT + /" to comment/uncomment that.

It's just that the two commands are not available in my notebooks (I have tried re-create several new notebooks but they all behave the same).

Comment: Please specify your operating system exactly because in Linux this works as expected.

Comment: I have this same problem on Win Machine in the company I work with MMA 9. Alt+/ do not work. One curiosity, are you admin in this machine? In my home windows I have no problem with Alt+/ in MMA 9. One detail that is different, my menu works, just shortcuts no.

Comment: @halirutan: my system is win 7 64-bit.

Comment: @Murta: I confirm that launching MMA9 as administrator solves both. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It seems this problem has not been fixed for version 12 yet.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution:**

*Murta 16 mins ago:*

> I have this same problem on Win Machine in the company I work with MMA 9. Alt+/ do not work. One curiosity, are you admin in this machine? In my home windows I have no problem with Alt+/ in MMA 9. One detail that is different, my menu works, just shortcuts no.

@Murta: I confirm that launching *Mathematica 9* as **administrator** solves both. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Interesting. I'll make some tests in the company, and report it to Wolfram as a bug. Nice that we funded the reason (but not the solution yet:)

Answer (score 3):

I am well aware that this topic is seven-year-vintage but I have encountered the same problem in Mathematica 12.1 and 12.3 on Windows 10 when I turned off dynamic updating because I was prompted to do so to accelerate some evaluations.

I have regained functionality for Ctrl+F and Alt+/ (comment toggle) by forcing dynamic updating with

`SetOptions[$FrontEnd, "DynamicUpdating" -> True]`

I have reported it as a bug to Wolfram together with the solution and I have received this answer

"*I am glad that it can be resolved with running
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, "DynamicUpdating" -> True]*"